# Selecting all elements of subsets if at least one element is selected (JAX)

Tags: python, numpy, jax

I have the following problem, for which I cannot manage to write a solution in JAX that is jittable and efficient.

I have a set of elements. Some of these elements are included (on the basis of a condition, which is not important now). The included elements are denoted by 1, the not-included elements by 0. For example, the array `arr = jnp.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])` indicates that I have 6 elements, the first of them included based on my condition.

These elements are grouped into subsets. I have a second array that indicates where each subset starts in the first array `arr`. For example, the array `subsets = jnp.array([0, 2])` indicates that the first subset starts at position 0 and the second subset starts at position 2.

Now, if one element is included based on `arr`, I would like to include all the elements in the same subset. In this example, the output should then be `[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

I have tried with a `jax.lax.fori_loop`, but it is slow.

```py
@jax.jit                                                                        
def select_subsets(arr, subsets):                 
    new_arr = arr.copy()            
    n_resid = subsets.shape[0]    
    indices = jnp.arange(arr.shape[0])       
                                                                                    
    def func(i, new_arr):    
        start = subsets[i]    
        stop = subsets[i+1]    
        arr_sliced = jnp.where((indices >= start) & (indices < stop), arr, 0.0)    
        sum_ = jnp.sum(arr_sliced)    
        new_arr = jnp.where(sum_ > 0.5, jnp.where((indices >= start) & (indices < stop), 1, new_arr), new_arr)    
        return new_arr                          
                                                 
    new_arr = jax.lax.fori_loop(0, n_resid-1, func, new_arr)    
    return new_arr
```

this function works if I use a `subsets` with the last element equal to the number of elements in `arr`, `subsets = jnp.array([0, 2, 6])`.

I then thought about writing a vectorized version (using `jax.numpy` operations), but I cannot manage to do it.

Is there a JAX guru that can help me with this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have a way to do it which is vectorized, but it instantiates a mask of shape (n_subsets, input_length).

Comment: @DavisYoshida cool! Is your version jittable? I imagine it will be more memory intensive than the `jax.lax.fori_loop` version I wrote, but is it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized version. It instantiates a mask with shape `len(subsets) x len(arr)`, which might be undesirable depending on how big those values are.

```py
           
@jax.jit                                                                             
def vectorized_select_subsets(arr, subsets):                         
    l, = arr.shape               
                               
    indices = jnp.arange(l)[None, :]
                
    # Broadcast to mask of shape (n_subsets, input_length)
    subset_masks = (
        (indices >= subsets[:-1, None])
        & (indices < subsets[1:, None])        
    )                                                           
                                                    
    # Shape (n_subsets,) array indicating whether each subset is included
    include_subset = jnp.any(subset_masks & arr[None, :], axis=1)          
                                                          
    # Reduce down columns 
    result = jnp.any(subset_masks & include_subset[:, None], axis=0).astype(jnp.int32)   
    return result
```

I timed this against the loop-based version on an array with length 512 and 32 subsets:

```
Loop: 6254.647 it/s
Vectorized: 37940.335 it/s
```